# Solidity returns "ParserError: Expected primary expression" on my code below, can anyone help?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

//Change the contract name to your token name
contract JONJonnywon {
    // Name your custom token
    string public constant name = "JONNYWON";

    // Name your custom token symbol
    string public constant symbol = "JON";

    uint8 public constant decimals = 2;

    // Contract owner will be your Link account
    address public owner;

    address public treasury;

    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed;
    mapping (address => uint256) private balances;

    event Approval(address indexed tokenholder, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;

        // Add your wallet address here which will contain your total token supply
        treasury = address(<0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413>);

        // Set your total token supply (default 1000)
        totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10**uint(decimals);

        balances[treasury] = totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), treasury, totalSupply);
    }

    function () external payable {
        revert();
    }

    function allowance(address _tokenholder, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_tokenholder][_spender];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_spender != address(0));
        require(_spender != msg.sender);

        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _tokenholder) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_tokenholder];
    }

    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_spender != address(0));
        require(_spender != msg.sender);

        if (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] <= _subtractedValue) {
            allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
        } else {
            allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender] - _subtractedValue;
        }

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);

        return true;
    }

    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_spender != address(0));
        require(_spender != msg.sender);
        require(allowed[msg.sender][_spender] <= allowed[msg.sender][_spender] + _addedValue);

        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender] + _addedValue;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);

        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != msg.sender);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_to != address(this));
        require(balances[msg.sender] - _value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        require(balances[_to] <= balances[_to] + _value);
        require(_value <= transferableTokens(msg.sender));

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - _value;
        balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_from != address(0));
        require(_from != address(this));
        require(_to != _from);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_to != address(this));
        require(_value <= transferableTokens(_from));
        require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] - _value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
        require(balances[_from] - _value <= balances[_from]);
        require(balances[_to] <= balances[_to] + _value);

        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender] - _value;
        balances[_from] = balances[_from] - _value;
        balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _value;

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        require(_newOwner != address(0));
        require(_newOwner != address(this));
        require(_newOwner != owner);

        address previousOwner = owner;
        owner = _newOwner;

        emit OwnershipTransferred(previousOwner, _newOwner);
    }

    function transferableTokens(address holder) public view returns (uint256) {
        return balanceOf(holder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the code says, you need to insert your address here (without "<>"). I've used one of Remix:

```
    // Add your wallet address here which will contain your total token supply
    treasury = address(0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c);
```

Comment: alberto: thank you, but I already did that but the error came anyway, do you have any further ideas? When I remove the ("<>") I get four errors instead of one.

Comment: @KalHal Check your compiler version, for me works fine. If you select version `0.5.10` in Remix, the contract will compile without errores (contract uses `^0.5.8`).